# how to calculate massive dissimilarity matrix in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am currently working on clustering some big data, about 30k rows,  the dissimilarity matrix just too big for R to handle,  I think this is not purely memory size problem.   Maybe there are some smart way to do this?

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines and provide a small sample of data as well as the code you've tried and what results you got.

Comment: You might want to look into other applications and algorithms. I frequently use ELKI with 110k to 2m objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is so large that base R can't easily cope, then you have several options:

- Work on a machine with more RAM.
- Use a commercial product, e.g. Revolution Analytics that supports working with larger data with R.

Here is an example using `RevoScaleR` the commercial package by Revolution.  I use the dataset `diamonds`, part of `ggplot2` since this contains 53K rows, i.e. a bit larger than your data.  The example doesn't make much analytic sense, since I naively convert factors into numerics, but it illustrates the computation on a laptop:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RevoScaleR)
artificial <- as.data.frame(sapply(diamonds, as.numeric))
clusters <- rxKmeans(~carat + cut + color + clarity + price, 
                     data=artificial, numClusters=6)
clusters$centers
```

This results in:

```
      carat      cut    color  clarity      price
1 0.3873094 4.073170 3.294146 4.553910   932.6134
2 1.9338503 3.873151 4.285970 3.623935 16171.7006
3 1.0529018 3.655348 3.866056 3.135403  4897.1073
4 0.7298475 3.794888 3.486457 3.899821  2653.7674
5 1.2653675 3.879387 4.025984 4.065154  7777.0613
6 1.5808225 3.904489 4.066285 4.066285 11562.5788
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to pay license fee if I use it?  Maybe I should try do a clustering on Hadoop instead.